# Angular's (9.1.15) MatDialog .afterClosed().subscribe() returning undefined, despite sending data on .close(..) method

Tags: angular9, subscribe

I'm working on a project making use of MatDialog on several instances.
In this particular example, I use two distinct modal dialogs in similar manner, the thing is one works properly as it should, and the other does not, returning `undefined` on the on `.afterClosed().subscribe()` data.

Code is as follows:
(only relevant lines as the code is quite extensive)

**stocks.component.ts**
*(main stock record management component)*

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { MatDialog } from '@angular/material/dialog';

import { NewModalComponent } from '../modal/new/new.component';
import { AddModalComponent } from '../modal/add/add.component';
...

export class StocksComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  constructor(
    private dialog: MatDialog,
    ...
  ) {}

  ...

  click(what) {
    switch (what) {
      case 'new':
        this.dialog.open(NewModalComponent, {
          width:      '440px',
          height:     '600px',
          autoFocus:  false,
        }).afterClosed().subscribe(
          (data) => {
console.log('modal-new > data :: ',data); // -- returns the passed object
          }
        );
      break;

      case 'add':
        this.dialog.open(AddModalComponent, {
          width:      '95%',
          height:     '85%',
          autoFocus:  false,
          data: {
            ...
          },
        }).afterClosed().subscribe(
          (data) => {
console.log('modal-add > data :: ',data); // -- returns undefined
          }
        );
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

**new.component.ts**
*(simple modal to select the type of new stock)*

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { MatDialogRef } from '@angular/material/dialog';
...

export class NewModalComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  constructor(
    private dialogRef: MatDialogRef<NewModalComponent>,
    ...
  ) {}

  ...

  click(what, data) {
    switch (what) {
      case 'newtype':
        this.dialogRef.close(data); // -- 'data' contains an object
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

**add.component.ts**
*(modal to add the products to the new stock)*

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { MatDialogRef, MAT_DIALOG_DATA } from '@angular/material/dialog';
...

export class AddModalComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  constructor(
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data,
    private dialogRef: MatDialogRef<AddModalComponent>,
  ) {}

  ...

  click(what) {
    switch (what) {
      case 'close':
        this.dialogRef.close(this.products); // -- 'this.products' contains an object
      break;
    }
  }

}
```

As you can see, both modals are *summoned* the same way and both make use of the same methods to subscribe to the data after closed, yet one successfully returns the data while the other does not. Am I missing something obvious..? ..or not so obvious?

Any help is appreciated, as I am in a rather tight schedule and stuck on this issue!!

Thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 1):

After a bit of debuging, and practically line-per-line testing, I discovered the source of the issue.

In my **add.component.ts** I have multiple child components, one of them being **list.component.ts** to display a complete list of the added products, as they are searched and selected (within another separate child component).
The problem resided in that **list** child component containing the following code:

```
  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.subscriptions.forEach((element) => { element.unsubscribe(); });
    this.dialog.closeAll();
  }
```

I found out that the `this.dialogRef.close(this.products);` line of the **add** component was indeed working properly, but upon receiving the 'close' command to itself, I suppose it triggers the close of its child components and when closing the **list** that `this.dialog.closeAll();` method got automatically triggered and would override / overlap the original `.close(..)`, thus resulting in the `undefined`.

This is probably an easy one for many of you, but I have little more than a year of experience in angular and so, small details like these can sometimes escape my graps.. at least for a while.

Anyway, I'm hoping this might help someone, either new or experienced, as all my searches regarding this issue only let to questions completely unrelated.

Best regards.

Comment: Thank you for this, it seems i had the same problem, i have been trying to solve this for hours but coudn't find out what was wrong.